# Create custom tag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my views I verry often have to write

```
<%=Model.T9n.TranslateById("someId");%>
```

Is there some way to make this more compact/readable. A custom tag maybe?

```
<asp:T9n>someId</asp:T9n>
```

or better

```
<t9n: someId />
```

**Note**
There are several (business) reasons why I can't use the default T9n tools in visual studio so that's why I've rolled my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about creating custom tags in MVC...

You could create your own custom HtmlHelper extension method. E.g.

```
<%=Html.T9n("someId");%>
```

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Thought about it, but not quiet what I want.

Comment: But in second thought it seems to best solution available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a custom control and get something like `<prefix:t9n translationID="someID" runat="server"/>`

Just Google for `web custom control` and you'll get tons of hits.

Comment: hmm, the syntax seems too verbose in comparisson with an HtmlHelper.